# Is counting sort present in std: sort in STL?

Tags: sorting, stl, counting-sort

Counting sort have time complexity: O(n+k) n-> size of input k-> abs. diff. b/w min and max value. In several cases counting sort is better than the comparison based sorting algorithm
 Is it present in std: sort in STL?  if no, Is there any reason?
 Also any function for counting sort available in STL?

Comment: Nothing prevents, in principle, `std::sort` implementation from detecting the (rather narrow and specialized) conditions that favor counting sort, and use that instead of the general-purpose sorting algorithm. I don't know of any implementation that actually does that; if I had to guess why, I'd suspect it's just not worth the trouble - the situations where counting sort is applicable are rare in practice. If you know your algorithm would benefit from it, feel free to implement it or find existing third-party implementation.

Comment: I can confirm that it's not present in Visual Studio's implementation of std::sort(), which is a variation of [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is counting sort present in std: sort in STL?

No, It's not present. The [`sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function is based on quick sort and other heuristics.

> if no, Is there any reason?

Probably because it's easy to implement. Check [psuedocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm)

```
count = array of k+1 zeros
for x in input do
    count[key(x)] += 1

total = 0
for i in 0, 1, ... k do
    count[i], total = total, count[i] + total

output = array of the same length as input
for x in input do
    output[count[key(x)]] = x
    count[key(x)] += 1 

return output
```

> Also any function for counting sort available in STL?

C++ STL provides the basic fitting data structures - arrays and vector which can be used for implementing counting sort.

`map` can also be used to implement counting sort, but it won't be O(n) anymore, since map operations are O(logn) complexity.

Comment: There are many other functions which are even easier to implement, like std:max, std::max_element etc. Frankly said, you argument didn't convince me.